# Update the glibc package Error

Tags: rhel, security, glibc, software-updates

I was asked to fix the vulnerabilities for RHEL 7: GLIBC(RHSA-2018:3092). Based on the output given by Nessus.

```
Remote package installed : glibc-2.17-222.el7
Should be                : glibc-2.17-260.el7

Remote package installed : glibc-common-2.17-222.el7
Should be                : glibc-common-2.17-260.el7

Remote package installed : glibc-devel-2.17-222.el7
Should be                : glibc-devel-2.17-260.el7

Remote package installed : glibc-headers-2.17-222.el7
Should be                : glibc-headers-2.17-260.el7
```

I tried to update all the rpm packages by the following command rpm -Uvh and it gave me the error failed dependencies. It said that glibc-common is needed but I include that package when updating in the command. Here is the command and the output below.

[image: Command and the output]

I am using x86_64 red hat server and when I found that glibc has 2 package orginally. which are i686 and x86_64.

[image]

I am using rpm package to update instead of yum.

Answer (score 1):

You have 32bit libraries installed as well (note the error refers to an `i686` package) so you need to upgrade those at the same time.

In general this is what `yum` will do for you.  `yum update glibc` should handle all the dependencies but won't update packages that aren't impacted.

Comment: yes I know that yum handle all the dependencies. Is there any other ways to do it?

Comment: However, there are 2 package installed which are i686 and x64

Comment: "you need to upgrade those at the same time"